# Can Control Element create an element?

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

I have a doubt regarding Control (Element). Is it possible to create the element with this power? Or just control something that already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonically, no, It does not let you create the element, just move it. That's part of the Flaw built into it to make it cheaper than regular Move Object. However, for example, Fire Control offers a "Flame Object" AP suggested in Ultimate Power that lets you do something similar. There's also the Ignite power in that book. It really becomes a GM purview thing.